# Isssue with creating multiple ggplots using for loop R

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I am trying to create 6 ggplot objects graphing the same graph but labeled differently, the labeling being stored in object{1:6}

```
ggrun<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6) 
for(i in ggrun) {assign(paste0("ggplot_", i), 
(ggplot(DF1, aes(x=X, y=Y, color=as.factor(get(paste0("object", i))[["cluster"]]))) + geom_point(fill = NA, size=1, alpha=0.6)))}
```

But this produced 6 identical objects, with the proper {1:6} names, but all with the same value of `object6`.

I checked my for loop too,

```
for(i in ggrun) {print(table(get(paste0("hdbscan_object", ggrun[i]))[["cluster"]]))}
```

and it spat out 6 distinct tables.

further, to make sure it was not my plotting command:

```
grid.arrange(grobs = g, ncol(3), nrow(2), top="Title of Graphs")
```

I manually assigned each item in the list object, e.g.:

```
g[[5]] = ggplot(DF1, aes(x=PC1, y=PC4, color=as.factor(get(paste0("object", "5"))[["cluster"]])))  
+ geom_point(fill = NA, size=1, alpha=0.6)
```

and it ran correctly.

Comment: Try to initialize a `list` of length i.e. `g <- vector('list', length(ggrun))`

Comment: @akrun I tried to initialize a list of length ggrun, ``g <- vector('list', length(ggrun))``, then I ran ``g[[i]] = ggplot(DF1, aes(x=PC1, y=PC4, color=as.factor(get(paste0("object", ggrun[i]))[["cluster"]]))) 
+ geom_point(fill = NA, size=1, alpha=0.6)`` and the same thing happened, only ``[[6]]`` contained information, corresponding to ``object6``

Comment: Please check what the value of `object1[["cluster"]]` and `object6[["cluster"]]`

Comment: @akrun They contain different values, if i put them into an object they are ``Values`` objects with ``typeof()`` double and ``class()`` numeric. Printing each of the contents, they are a series of numbers corresponding to the cluster identity ``1 1 1 1 1 2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4``

Comment: IN your code example, i didn't see the `for` loop  in the second code block i.e. `g <- vector('list', length(ggrun)); for(i in ggrun) g[[i]] <-  ggplot(DF1, aes(x=PC1, y=PC4, color=as.factor(get(paste0("object", ggrun[i]))[["cluster"]]))) 
+ geom_point(fill = NA, size=1, alpha=0.6)`

Comment: @akrun the code starting with ``g[[i]] =`` ? The idea for that code was given to me by a coworker and when we discussed, there was no for in that command. I will add to beginning

Comment: Ok, it should have a `for` loop because otherwise, there is no `i` defined.

Comment: Thats what I thought initially but I thought it was R iterative magic, like when you write ``df1[df1$1 == "1"] <- "N/A"``
Adding the for in the beginning makes the code work, still dont know why my first forloop attempt didnt work but it isnt too important maybe.

Comment: You can also do this with `lapply` i.e. `g <- lapply(ggrun, function(i) ggplot(DF1, aes(x=PC1, y=PC4, color=as.factor(get(paste0("object", i))[["cluster"]])))  + geom_point(fill = NA, size=1, alpha=0.6))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ggplot works a bit weirdly with for loops as many of the internal operations seem to rely on pointers rather than actually storing the values. To work around this, you will often have to create a new environment for them to protect from the value that the pointer points at from being changed.

You can try storing the values in a list and using the `lapply` function:

```
g <- lapply(1:6, 
            function (x){
                ggplot(DF1, aes(x=PC1, y=PC4, 
                       color=as.factor(get(paste0("object", x))[["cluster"]]))) + 
                    geom_point(fill = NA, size=1, alpha=0.6)
            }
     )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using `mget` :

```
library(ggplot2)

lapply(mget(paste0("object", 1:6)), function(x) {
  ggplot(DF1, aes(x=PC1, y=PC4, 
                  color= factor(x[["cluster"]]))) + 
    geom_point(fill = NA, size=1, alpha=0.6)
}) -> list_plots

list_plots
```